# Create multiple artboards with unique sizes from list of pre-typed measurements

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, script, measurement

I have several projects that need 15-20 artboards in one file with multiple unique sizes. Right now, I create each artboard individually working of a long list of typed out measurements . Is there a script or something that would allow me to copy and paste in the measurements for each artboard and then have illustrator create them all at once? It would save me hours of work a week if I can find a way to do this.

Comment: One *could* probably write a simple script to build rectangles from a list of measurements... then convert those rectangles to artboards. Check the [scripting guide](https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/scriptingJavascript/creatingPathsShapes.html)